# Let me easily get the souce code for my comments after the 5 minute edit grace period

Tags: feature-request, comments

When I start hunting for "duplicate pools", and I want to make a single comment with links to the entire pool.

If often happens that I make a comment, only to find another item of the duplicate pool the following day.

So what I'd like is to:

- take the source of the old comment (THIS is what is missing)
- add the new link to it
- post the updated list
- delete the old one

in order to concentrate the links further.

I understand that putting and edit button on uneditable comments may be bad, but I wish there was a way to get that source easily.

The only way I see currently is with the SEDE.

Maybe enable the edit button, but if it is clicked add a huge alert: "You can't edit anymore!!!".

Some other mechanism would be fine as well.

Comment: As the answer to the other question says, you can use SEDE for this. Not the most elegant way, but it works.

Comment: I have added a new answer there, with an easier way to see the source of given comment. :)